# Android app hanging (not crashing) on real device with illegal method access of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using `RecyclerView` in my app and my app just hangs (doesn't quit, just animations stop and app becomes completely unresponsive) with the following logs in console:

```
05-01 09:23:39.075 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.ulouder.ulouder-1/libuLouderNative.so 0x41db4c90
05-01 09:23:39.075 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.ulouder.ulouder-1/libuLouderNative.so 0x41db4c90
05-01 09:23:39.075 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.ulouder.ulouder-1/libuLouderNative.so 0x41db4c90, skipping init
05-01 09:23:39.345 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41dab7c8 time:89397538
05-01 09:23:39.350 2281-2319/system_process I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{430106a0 u0 com.ulouder.ulouder/com.ulouder.activities.MainActivity t19} time:89397539
05-01 09:23:42.540 21296-21741/com.ulouder.ulouder D/uLouder: [01 23 2016 09:23:42] Fired event with data: feed loaded nearby
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isUpdated ()Z from Lcom/ulouder/viewholders/PostViewHolder;)
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isUpdated, referenced from method com.ulouder.viewholders.PostViewHolder.access$super
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17616: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isUpdated ()Z
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0031
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition (IIZ)V from Lcom/ulouder/viewholders/PostViewHolder;)
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition, referenced from method com.ulouder.viewholders.PostViewHolder.access$super
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17600: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.flagRemovedAndOffsetPosition (IIZ)V
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0053
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isRemoved ()Z from Lcom/ulouder/viewholders/PostViewHolder;)
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isRemoved, referenced from method com.ulouder.viewholders.PostViewHolder.access$super
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17613: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isRemoved ()Z
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0058
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.clearPayload ()V from Lcom/ulouder/viewholders/PostViewHolder;)
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.clearPayload, referenced from method com.ulouder.viewholders.PostViewHolder.access$super
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17595: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.clearPayload ()V
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x007c
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isAdapterPositionUnknown ()Z from Lcom/ulouder/viewholders/PostViewHolder;)
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.isAdapterPositionUnknown, referenced from method com.ulouder.viewholders.PostViewHolder.access$super
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17609: Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder;.isAdapterPositionUnknown ()Z
05-01 09:23:42.720 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0086
...
```

It just goes on for many methods of `RecyclerView`, crashing the whole app (or thread) with this at the end of the log:

```
05-01 09:23:42.730 21296-21296/com.ulouder.ulouder W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41873ce0)
```

Why am I getting this? This happens on real device (Samsung Galaxy S3) with Android 4.4.4 (API 19) while there's no problem with my emulator with Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, Android was misleading. There was nothing to do with those error messages. There was an actual null pointer exception on view binding which crashed the whole thread, but somehow it wasn't reported correctly to logcat.